# How to connect mysql db to my single page angularjs app?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I have a website where i need to perform CRUD operation with my mysql db, I have got so many things on the internet that i dont know what to use, could anyone please guide me??
The website is a directory which will allow businesses to register, insert/delete/update their listings.Thanks

Comment: And, you start with telling what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Single Page Applications can generally be said to be entirely client-side, that is, the HTML that is displayed to the end-user is generated on the client itself through Javascript.

When you want to work with a shared back-end database server you would write a web-service (presumably using a RESTful JSON endpoint, as that's what all the cool kids are using thesedays, no love for XML and SOAP :/ ) and you would then use `XmlHttpRequest` to make requests to this webservice which then performs the CRUD database operations for you.